# How does the loss landscape look like or change when a model is overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, overfitting, loss

My understanding is that when a model starts overfitting, it no longer learns useful features and starts remembering the training data set. Given enough epochs and sufficient parameters, a model can over-fit any arbitrary dataset. My question is how does the loss landscape look like for the training dataset vs the test dataset when a model is overfitting? Is there a weird dip around some point in the training dataset but the same dip is not there in the test dataset?